# How to hide a view from certain roles?

Tags: views, users

I am trying to hide some views (and their menu links) from anonymous users and some other roles i have created, how this can be done ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the views you have page settings option

In that there is access option

You can change the access to role and 
by changing the settings u can assign roles who has the permission to access the view.

Comment: Omg, i feel so stupid, i lost about two hours searching for this and it was so easy. Thank you very much !!!